# XmlSerialization Collection as Array

Tags: c#, .net, xml-serialization

I'm trying to serialize a custom class that needs to use multiple elements of the same name.
I've tried using xmlarray, but it wraps them in another elements.

I want my xml to look like this.

```
<root>
     <trees>some text</trees>
     <trees>some more text</trees>
</root>
```

My code:

```
[Serializable(), XmlRoot("root")]
public class test
{
      [XmlArray("trees")]
      public ArrayList MyProp1 = new ArrayList();

      public test()
      {
           MyProp1.Add("some text");
           MyProp1.Add("some more text");  
      }
}
```

Comment: have you tried setting attribute XmlArrayItem(typeof(System.String)) along with the XMLArray ?

Comment: yes, it creates something like the xml below
<root>
   <tree>
      <string>some text</string>
      <string>some more text</string>
   </tree>
</root>

Comment: Good question, bad title.
Title should be "How to flatten an array/list/collection with XmlSerializer"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try just using `[XmlElement("trees")]`:

```
[Serializable(), XmlRoot("root")]
public class test
{
    [XmlElement("trees")]
    public List<string> MyProp1 = new List<string>();

    public test()
    {
        MyProp1.Add("some text");
        MyProp1.Add("some more text");
    }
}
```

Note I changed `ArrayList` to `List<string>` to clean up the output; in 1.1, `StringCollection` would be another option, although that has different case-sensitivity rules.

Answer (score 0):

(edit: obsoleted - my [second post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496488/xmlserialization-collection-as-array/499768#499768) (`[XmlElement]`) is the way to go - I'm leaving this for posterity in using `xsd.exe`)

`xsd.exe` is your friend. Copy the xml you want into a file (`foo.xml`), then use:

```
xsd foo.xml
xsd foo.xsd /classes
```

Now read `foo.cs`; you can use this either directly, or just for inspiration.

(edit: output snipped - not helpful any more)