# XmlSerialization and List

Tags: xml, list, serialization, xmlserializer

I have the following class

```
public class Notifications : List<Notification> { }
```

Unfortunately, when it's serialized it looks like

```
<ArrayOfNotification>
  <Notification>
  ...
```

How can I get that root node to be **Notifications**?
I've tried a few different attributes on the class, but none compile.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496488/xmlserialization-collection-as-array for some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
...
[XmlType(TypeName="Notifications")]
public class Notifications ...
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured there had to be an attribute, I just didn't find that one.  I had tried XmlElement, XmlArray, etc